# Rendering nested form fields in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, simple-form, nested-forms, has-many-through

In our app, we have, among others, these three models:

```
class PackContent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :pack

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pack_contents
  has_many :packs, through: :pack_contents

class Pack < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pack_contents
  has_many :products, through: :pack_contents
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pack_contents
```

A pack has multiple pack_contents, which are basically a product and some specific productvariants. The join table (pack_contents) looks like this:

[image: pack_contents]

I am now trying to display these pack_contents in a usable manner, but keep running into a wall.

I have tried:

```
.pack-product-rows
  - @pack.pack_contents.each do |pc|
    = f.simple_fields_for pc do |p|
      = render :partial => 'pack_product_row', :locals => { :p => p, :pc => pc }
```

But then, upon saving, I get an error saying:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in Admin::PacksController#update
unknown attribute: pack_content
```

And the form field name attributes are wrong, they don't account for multiple contents as they don't include an index.

When I try this:

```
.pack-product-rows
  - @pack.pack_contents.each do |pc|
    = f.simple_fields_for :pack_contents do |p|
      = render :partial => 'pack_product_row', :locals => { :p => p, :pc => pc }
```

It renders every partial twice, which, I suppose, is to be expected.

If i don't loop over the contents and just use simple_fields_for, I get the output I want, but not how I want it. I can render the fields with `p.input_field :id` and the likes, but I need access to the pack_contents in order to display my data like this: (input fields meant to be hidden)

[image]

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: In your `class Pack` you have typed `has_many :product, through: :pack_contents`. It should be `has_many :products, through: :pack_contents`. Was it a typing mistake ?

Comment: Yea, typo. I got `:products` in the app. Will fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've understood what you're asking but if you just want an access to the current item being automatically iterated via `simple_fields_for`, then you can access it through the form builder as `p.object`.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are trying to build the nested form on the `views/packs/show.html.erb` where in you have the `@pack` instance variable initialized to a `pack` from the database. So on this page you will have a `- simple_form_for @pack` form inside which you want to nest over the `pack_contents`. 
Now the `simple_form_fields` method of the `simple_form` gem works just like the `fields_for` method in rails. Based on that I am giving you the code below. It should work properly but you may have make a few syntactical changes to make it work.

```
- simple_form_for @pack do |pack_form|
  .pack-product-rows
    - @pack.pack_contents.each do |pack_content|
      = f.simple_fields_for :pack_contents, pack_content do |pack_content_fields|
        = render :partial => 'pack_product_row', :locals => { :pack => @pack, :pack_content => pack_content, :pack_content_fields => pack_content_fields}
```

Now in the partial `pack_product_row` you will need to use the three locals passed. You must be already using pack and pack_content but whatever fields for pack_contents you want to display should be written as `pack_content_fields.field_name`. If your naming convention is correct for all the fields then these fields will be either empty if the pack_content is empty or having the value stored in the database.